# Tableau Parameter Swapping Measures with Calculated Fields

Tags: parameters, tableau-api

Desired Formula: I would like for the units or dollars to appear (based on parameter selection) for only the year 2013, is this possible ? "Dollars Units" is the parameter.

```
IF YEAR([Date]) = 2013 THEN [Dollars Units] END
```

However no values appear, just "ABC" when I place it in the measures (after being in dimensions).  I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Parameter to control whether dollars or units are shown called "Dollars Units"

```
CASE [Dollars Units]
      WHEN 'Units' THEN SUM([Units])
      WHEN 'Dollars' THEN SUM([Sales])
 END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what I needed to do:

```
IF YEAR([Order Date]) = 2013 THEN
        (CASE [Dollars Units]
     WHEN 'Units' THEN [Units]
     WHEN 'Dollars' THEN [Sales]
END)
END
```